# UIButton background color for highlighted/selected state issue

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've a `UIButton` and I've created an extension to add background color for different state.

**I'm using the following code:**

```
extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forState: forState)
    }
}


// Set Button Title and background color for different states
    self.donateButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.donateButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.donateButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    self.donateButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    self.donateButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Selected)
    self.donateButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Selected)
```

> My Problem is that it is not picking up proper `UIButton` background color and title color for highlighted/selected state.

[image: Normal state]
[image: Highlighted state]

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I found the issue, `UIButton` was set to **System**.I simply changed it to **Custom**, it started working as expected.

Comment: i had the same problem, making it custom did the trick. The pressed state is Highlighted instead of what I thought (selected) :S.

Comment: Thanks mate! @Ashish Verma

Answer (score 5):

Update Swift 4

```
extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
    }

}
```

Event 
Button Action
Show Touch On Highlight

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5, IOS 13+

```
extension UIButton {

  func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, for forState: UIControl.State) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
    let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work is that you have not set the correct state: you are missing the `[ .highlighted, .selected ]` state, and so it falls back to plain `.normal`.

When both `isSelected` and `isHighlighted` are true, UIKit looks explicitly for the state-combination of the two, and will not accept any of them individually.

The original code extended with the missing state (and updated to valid syntax in Swift 5):

```
self.donateButton.setBackgroundColor(.green, for: [ .highlighted, .selected ])
self.donateButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: [ .highlighted, .selected ])
```

Answer (score 0):

When your `UIButton` is selected. If you focus on the button, it will not highlight the button as state `.Highlighted`. If it is not selected, it will highlight it as your will. For it regards you have background image in your button, it will use the default effect to highlight a image. If you want to change the state to `.Selected`, you have to set the variable `selected` of `UIButton` to true.

Answer (score 0):

To implement custom button illumination, you need:
- Set in the storyboard the background color and alpha that you want to see, when button is pressed
- At the time of initialization, set the background and alpha as a button that is not pressed
-Implement three methods for the button (Touch Down / Touch Up Side / Touch Drag Outside)
- In them, change the button illumination