# UIButton setTitle Colour Changing not working

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, uicolor

I have created scroll view programmatically and created N number of buttons using for loop, but now I need to change setTitle color accordingly the button selected or unselected

```
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,50,self.view.frame.size.width,40)];
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;


for (int i = 0; i<_pagesNameArray.count; i++) {
    
   
    
  
    
    self.button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(i*150, 0, 150, 40);
   
    
   
    self.button.tag = i;
    
    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapSegmentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.button setTitle:[_pagesNameArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  [_scrollView addSubview:self.button];
    
   
}
[self setupSelector];
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in _scrollView.subviews) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
}
_scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;

[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
```

I also tried this method but, it's not working. Can anyone help me out?

```
   [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

[image]

Comment: Might be help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562379/uibutton-background-color-for-highlighted-selected-state-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created 3 different type of buttons and given tag to each button

```
self.button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
self.button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 30);
self.button.tag = 0;
self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapSegmentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.button setTitle:@"LOCAL REPORTS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 // [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.04f green:0.14f blue:0.19f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald-Regular" size:20.0f];

[_scrollView addSubview:self.button];


self.buttonNews = [[UIButton alloc]init];
self.buttonNews.frame = CGRectMake(135, 0, 180, 30);
self.buttonNews.tag = 1;
self.buttonNews.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.buttonNews addTarget:self action:@selector(tapSegmentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.buttonNews setTitle:@"NEWS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[self.buttonNews setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.buttonNews.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald-Regular" size:20.0f];
self.buttonNews.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald-Regular" size:20.0f];
[_scrollView addSubview:self.buttonNews];



self.buttonTop = [[UIButton alloc]init];
self.buttonTop.frame = CGRectMake(135*2, 0, 180, 30);
self.buttonTop.tag = 2;
self.buttonTop.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.buttonTop addTarget:self action:@selector(tapSegmentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.buttonTop setTitle:@"TOP PHOTOS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[self.buttonTop setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 self.buttonTop.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald-Regular" size:20.0f];
self.buttonTop.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald-Regular" size:20.0f];
[_scrollView addSubview:self.buttonTop];
[self animateButton];



  -(void) animateButton
   {
[self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.04f green:0.14f blue:0.19f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonNews setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonTop setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if (self.currentIndex == 0) {
    [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.04f green:0.14f blue:0.19f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonNews setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonTop setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
if (self.currentIndex == 1) {
    [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonNews setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.04f green:0.14f blue:0.19f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonTop setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
if (self.currentIndex == 2) {
    [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonNews setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonTop setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.04f green:0.14f blue:0.19f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tapSegmentButtonAction:(UIbutton *)sender
 {

 UIbutton *button=sender.tag;
 [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] 
          forState:UIControlStateSelected];


 }
```

Comment: you can do one more thing....You can add object for all buttons in one array...pass the index no of button and ref the UIbutton on the particular object and then you can change its colour on selection.

Example= UIbutton *button=[nameOfArray objectatindex:index no];
 [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] 
          forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Comment: I solved this one like I created different UIBtton instead of creating UIButton using For Loop. Thank you

Comment: one more thing...the UI as shown above in simulator..Use  UISegment control...It will be easy for you.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro its a page view controller as well